# How to align based on a middle dash (or other character) inside cells

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

How can I obtain in a simple way this format inside cells of a table?, I mean all dashes aligned, when I am `using a proportional font`.

example:

[image]

Note:  There are more cells on each row, and table uses borders, so I think that using three consecutive cells without borders, is not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well using a table is not exactly would I would recommend but keeping to the request of your posting you can try something like this...

```
<table id="myTable">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2039</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>49</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>560</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And some small CSS

```
#myTable tr td:first-child{ text-align:right; }
```

Comment: Sorry, this do not works for my purpose. I have edited the question to claryfy

Comment: I see, have you tried the following....

    <tr>
        <td><span style="width:30px; text-align:right;">1</span></td>
        <td>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>

Comment: for now, is the best I have, please edit your answer in this way. Thanks